# Erratic behavior of smooth div scroller

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling

I have a webpage that uses Smooth Div Scroll to scroll through a product catalogue using divs. The scroller acts fine when the entire range of products displayed is wider than the page (when scroll is actually needed) but when the range is narrower it starts skipping and jumping when you near the left and right hotpoints. An example of the behaviour is shown here:

http://www.iana.si/teme/tropical-energy-12m-4leta-tid596

Can someone help me out why this is happening?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you are using jQuery 1.4 min versiona and there is a

> TypeError: c.easing[a] is not a function

Try using jQuery 1.8

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: This does seem to help. Still a bit shaky but a lot better. Thankks for noticing an old version of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Smooth Div Scroll requires that the content in the scroller is wider than the scroller itself. As you say, if not there's no need for a scroller.

I suggest you rethink your interface or use the options and callbacks to code something that disables the scroller if the content is too short.